# PSD To Xamarin Android UI

Tags: xaml, user-interface, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017, psd

Is it Possible to convert HTML, CSS UI into Xamarin Android UI?  if yes Kindly tell me how.

I tried to use "EXPORT KIt" but it isn't properly configured with Adobe Photoshop. Any other way to convert? Thanks All of you in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a tool that converts HTML + CSS into Android layout files? If yes, I do not think such a tool exists. You'd have to manually code the UI in XML. You can get started with this documentation > https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html